# Updating an entity Symfony 2.6

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to update an entity.
I have a form, who returns an array to my formHandler.

There is my onSuccess()

```
public function onSuccess($createIndicatorModelFormModel)
{
    $this->em->persist($this->indicatorModelTransformer->transform($createIndicatorModelFormModel));
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

I can't persist an array, that's why i've made an transformer.

The problem is when i'm trying to persist or merge. He is trying to INSERT an new row.. What can i do ?

Comment: Do you `clone` your object, or create another from it at a moment during your process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call method persist() when initializing a new object. Use it without persisting it when updating. To resolve this issue i need more code. Or my guess based on your question is to simply commenting out the persist part.

Comment: Yeha, u're right, that was the prob. Thanks you dude :)